# What after installing sublime lint?

Tags: php, text-editors, sublime-text-3

I think things could have been a little more simpler if the developers wanted it.It is really annoyinng to keep searching google to make my php and javascript lint.

I followed this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132469/configuring-the-sublimelinter-plugin-to-use-php

There are plugins such as sublime lint,sublime linter,code_sniffer etc.Are they all the same?

I have done all the right things

```
Installed package control.
Installed sublime php lint.
Installed sublime js hint.
Installed node.js
added the json in settings.user
```

It it still does not work.

*This is what the github tells us to do : PHP - syntax checking via php -l(I have no idea what this means)*

Can any body show me a simpler way of linting my code?

Comment: Consider CudaText app, it has also CudaLint and PHP linter, etc. Easier to setup.

Answer (score 1):

You should pretty much just need to install sublimelint from Package Control, restart Sublime Text once, and make sure you have any external dependencies as listed in the README.

If you're using SublimeLinter (which I consider to be a hostile fork of sublimelint), the only extra step *should* be to install the language-specific linting package from package control. Remember, SublimeLinter3 is a completely different project from SublimeLinter (2), as they forked my project verbatim again to get ST3 support. The instructions in that older answer are probably for Sublime Text 2.

In PHP's case, you need to have PHP installed on your system and in your PATH. If it's not in your PATH, you need to change your linter settings to point to the correct executable.

So, does running `php -v` from a command line produce any output? If not, you probably need to install it or point to it in your sublimelint or SublimeLinter settings.

Comment: this is the path to my php.exe : C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php ,should i add some json to settings .user for pointing?

Comment: "sublimelinter": true,
 "sublimelinter_executable_map":
 {
  "css": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
  "javascript": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
  "php": "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php.exe"
 }

Comment: Are you on Sublime Text 2 or 3?

Comment: sublime text 3,sorry for tagging sublimetext2